# Deploy Coldbox Application to an existing Adobe Coldfusion 2021 instance

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox, coldfusion-2021

I have a simple Coldbox REST application that just calls the following function and returns either 0 or 1:

```
function getTurnstileData(location, type, rfid){
    spTurnstile = new storedProc(procedure='pr_dtr_timedata_check', datasource='dsTurnstile');
    spTurnstile.addParam(type='in',cfsqltype='CF_SQL_VARCHAR', value=location);
    spTurnstile.addParam(type='in',cfsqltype='CF_SQL_VARCHAR', value=type);
    spTurnstile.addParam(type='in',cfsqltype='CF_SQL_VARCHAR', value=rfid);
    spTurnstile.addParam(type='out',cfsqltype='CF_SQL_VARCHAR', value='');
    spTurnstile.addProcResult(name='result');

    result = spTurnstile.execute().getProcResultSets().result;

    return result;
}
```

Using the coldbox server `server start --rewritesEnable cfengine=adobe@2021`, the application runs properly (http://127.0.0.1:56217/index.cfm/api/checkEntry?location=test&type=IN&rfid=248426891)
[image: Result using Coldbox server]

However, when I use the exact same code (with all the same mappings and data source) and run it in an existing Adobe Coldfusion 2021, it shows an error.

```
11:34:28.028 - Database Exception - in C:/ColdFusion_2021_WWEJ_win64/ColdFusion2021/ColdFusion/cfusion/CustomTags/com/adobe/coldfusion/base.cfc : line 381
        Error Executing Database Query.
        
11:34:28.028 - Database Exception - in C:/ColdFusion_2021_WWEJ_win64/ColdFusion2021/ColdFusion/cfusion/CustomTags/com/adobe/coldfusion/base.cfc : line 381
        Error Executing Database Query.
```

#### Result using existing Adobe Coldfusion Server (A)

[image: Result using existing Adobe Coldfusion Server (A)]

#### Result using existing Adobe Coldfusion Server (B)

[image: Result using existing Adobe Coldfusion Server (B)]

Is there a proper way to deploy a coldbox application to an existing Adobe Coldfusion Server instance? I cannot seem to find any information in the documentation.

Comment: Hi did you find any solution for this?